# Difference between ROC-AUC and Multiclass AUC (MAUC)

Tags: machine-learning, classification, roc, auc, multi-class

I am trying to understand the interpretation of these metrics in a multiclass scenario: `ROC-AUC` and `MAUC`. Scikit-learn provides an implementation for [ROC-AUC](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html) score, which can be used for both binary and `multiclass` problems.

However, some studies such as [2](https://journalofbigdata.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s40537-020-00349-y), [3](https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.1800), [4](https://gist.github.com/stulacy/672114792371dc13b247) and [5](https://github.com/pritomsaha/Multiclass_AUC/blob/master/multiclass_auc.ipynb) suggest averaging class-wise AUC in `multiclass`.

My experiments with this metrics yield different results. Do they then evaluate to different quantities?

For clarity, I used [4](https://github.com/pritomsaha/Multiclass_AUC/blob/master/multiclass_auc.ipynb) implementation as well as [sklearn's ROC-AUC](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html). I the case of  `sklearn`'s, I set the hyperparameters as:

```
roc_auc = metrics.roc_auc_score(y_test, ypred, average='weighted', 
    multi_class='ovo',labels=labels)
```

With `Random Forest` classifier, we obtained:

```
ROC-AUC:  0.58 # sklearn's roc-auc-score
MAUC:     0.69
```

This is more than a `10%` difference so the two values are not close at all.

**EDIT**

***References:***

[1](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html) sklearn's roc-auc score: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html

[2](https://journalofbigdata.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s40537-020-00349-y) Tanha, J., Abdi, Y., Samadi, N., Razzaghi, N., Asadpour, M.: Boosting methods
for multi-class imbalanced data classification: an experimental review. Journal of
Big Data 7(1), 1–47 (2020)

[3](https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.1800) Wang, R., Tang, K.: An empirical study of MAUC in multi-class
problems with uncertain cost matrices. CoRR abs/1209.1800 (2012),
http://arxiv.org/abs/1209.1800

[4](https://gist.github.com/stulacy/672114792371dc13b247) https://gist.github.com/stulacy/672114792371dc13b247

[5](https://github.com/pritomsaha/Multiclass_AUC/blob/master/multiclass_auc.ipynb) https://github.com/pritomsaha/Multiclass_AUC/blob/master/multiclass_auc.ipynb

Comment: Could you please include full citations for those references? If you have the titles, it’s usually pretty easy to find full citations on Google Scholar. That way, if the links rot, we still have the references.

Comment: You may also want to reenumerate the references in the paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sklearn implementation offers different options for `multi_class` and `average` which explains the main difference: the Hand-Till paper and the implementations you linked use a one-vs-one approach as you do in your sklearn call, but also uses a macro-average compared to your weighted average approach.

There's another issue that prevents the scores from agreeing completely, though it will be more minor than the averaging issue.  The gist and github implementations both sort the samples by probability, but ties are left up to the numpy sorting.  In sklearn however, a tie of probabilities is handled by having a sloped line in the ROC curve, which also affects the area computation.  Tweaking the toy example in [5] (since gunes pointed out the difference there, even though the classes are balanced and so the averaging plays no role) to have no ties in probability scores yields equal scores.

Comment: thank you for this detail answer.

Answer (score 2):

Reference [5] seems to use an approximation in the function `a_value` but that doesn't seem to be the way the AUC is calculated in `sklearn`. It uses the method [`_average_multiclass_ovo_score`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/baf828ca126bcb2c0ad813226963621cafe38adb/sklearn/metrics/_base.py#L132), whose `binary_metric` is given as [`_binary_roc_auc_score`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/baf828ca126bcb2c0ad813226963621cafe38adb/sklearn/metrics/_ranking.py#L334). This method calls the `roc_curve` and general purpose `auc` method. I don't think this implements the logic embedded in the fourth reference.

Even the toy example given in [5] does not give the same value as sklearn.

Comment: sklearn's `ovo` "Computes the average AUC of all possible pairwise combinations of classes" as far the documentation. Maybe you mean sklearn's `ovr`?

Comment: You're right. Will look into sklearn's implementation.

Comment: Does this suggest the tow metric measures are different?

Comment: Yes, it appears the sklearn does not use the approximated formula, which is equation 3 in this paper: https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1023/A:1010920819831.pdf

Comment: I think Hand and Till use "estimate" to mean using a test sample to estimate the true/asymptotic AUC.  The formula they give is equivalent to the area under the ROC curve, except that ties need to be handled (they call this out in the last line of page 173, but I don't see any further mention of how to adjust the procedure when there are ties?).